# ITunesConnect doesn't show different language options

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add a Chinese version of my app description to itunes connect, but they're not showing me the Chinese option, only English. What is going on? For my other app it shows me the full list of languages. I don't understand what's different. Why is my localized metadata not editable?

Yes I tried Safari too, same thing happened.

[image]

Is it because I'm waiting for a review for my latest version (1.2)? I already have 1.0 in `Ready for Sale`, but 1.2 is still in `Waiting for Review`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can add localization to your app when its status is like 'Prepare
  for Submission' or when the app version is enable to editing.

  As per your current situation, I can suggest you that you should
  reject the binary and upload a new version. By the time, You can edit
  the localization for your current version.

  To add the localization, Please follow below steps:

  1. Go to iTunes Connect & select your app.
  2. Select "App Information" from left panel.
  3. Click on the primary language. It'll show a drop down with available localization languages.
  4. Now, You can select the language(s) in which you want your app to be localized.
     [image: Select primary language to see drop down]

[image: Select language to be localized]

[image: App is localized with selected Language]

You can also refer this link for more information:- [Display
   localization in app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH28-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its because your app status in `Waiting for Review` state. You can edit certain metadata when your application is in `Prepare for Submission` state.

> You can add a new localization only when your app status allows
>   editing, such as the Prepare for Submission status like adding new language.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH28-SW1) for more info. Hope it helps.